# Vue.js - Prop Undefined

Tags: javascript, parent-child, vuejs2

I'm passing a root prop (object called "columnCollapsed") to a child component called "data-row" (see below) but it shows as undefined. Could this be a scope issue? Its probably something simple - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Snippet which seems to be the culprit:

```
<tr is="data-row" v-for="record in recordsFiltered" :record="record" :columnCollapsed="columnCollapsed"></tr>
```

Here is the full fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/wk7k8Lfa/1/

Image of Chrome Vue DevTools - showing variable available at root, but undefined at child level:
[image: Image of Chrome Vue DevTools - showing variable available at root, but undefined at child level:]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do `:column-collapsed="columnCollapsed"`.

You want hyphens in html, camelCase in JS. I *know* this and it bites me in the ass regularly.

Comment: Wow! Thanks Bill! This has nipping me in the ass for a while now!! Thank you! On a related note, I'm not sure if you looked at the fiddle, but I have some filters used for formatting numbers (formatDollars, formatPercent, etc.) and I repeated the code in the child and parent - do you have a tip for making parent filters available to children?

Comment: They sound similar so I'd consider putting them in a mixin and import them into the components I need. If you find yourself needing them everywhere you can make them global with `Vue.filter('formatPercent', ...)`.

Comment: There's no way to just share with children though.

Comment: Great! Thanks again Bill!